# PnP JavaScript Library With jQuery In SharePoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am creating a web application  in share point to access the share point data. To show the data in browser i am using jquery. It is showing 404 exception and

> [ProcessHttpClientResponseException: Error making HttpClient request
>   in queryable: [404] Not Found][1]

Also it is showing error at path url.

Please help me out.

```
{               <script type="text/javascript">  
                const mySp = $pnp.sp.configure({
                    mode: 'no-cors'
                        })
                  mySp.web.currentUser.get().then((result) => {
                  console.log(result)
                    })  
                   $(document).ready(function(){  
                         $pnp.sp.web.webs.get().then(function(result) {  
                        <!This is the path url here it is showing error>
                          if(result.length > 0)  
                           $('#countid').html("Total subsites: "+ 
                              result.length);  

                                for(var i=0; i< result.length; i++){  
                            $("#webTable tbody").append( "<tr>"+   
                                "<td>"+result[i].Title+"</td>"+   
                               "<td>"+result[i].Id+"</td>"+   
                                  "<td>"+result[i].Created+"</td>"+   
                              "<td>"+result[i].WebTemplate+"</td>"+ "</tr>");  
                        }  
                           }).catch(function(err){ alert(err);});  

                 });  
</script>  

}
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pnp.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ProcessHttpClientResponseException: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [404] Not Found
    at new t (http://ie-dev-sp72:549/sites/jqueryindex/SiteAssets/scripts/pnp.js:1:9369)
    at http://ie-dev-sp72:549/sites/jqueryindex/SiteAssets/scripts/pnp.js:1:53029
_api/web/webs:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)            these all are the eroors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the network tab in chromedev tools. 
This will give you the url request you are sending and a better print out of the error response.

Post those and I can help you further.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: True but I dont have enough rep to comment.